# Android Glide: prevent white image if the request fails

Tags: android, android-glide

So I'm just interested if I could prevent Glide from loading a white (null) image into an ImageView if the url provided is wrong..
I'd like to keep the image that I provide in XML if it can't find the image (because it might be wrong due to user input).

I've tried returning true in the listener, but I guess that's just for animation handling.
Many thanks!

```
 public static void loadImage(String url, Context c, ImageView target) {
    Glide.with(c).load(url).listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }
    }).into(target);
}
```

}

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can use `.error(mDefaultBackground) --> Sets a Drawable to display if a load fails.` to keep image. just like below

```
Drawable mDefaultBackground = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_background);

Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(uri)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(mDefaultBackground).into(target);
```

from [documentation](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/330/com/bumptech/glide/DrawableRequestBuilder.html#error(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

Comment: This helped me, I just adjusted the static function to get the current drawable from the ImageView so I don't have to load it manually and keep track of what the actual drawable was. Thanks!

Comment: you can directly use resource id rather than creating a Drawable: `.error(R.drawable.ic_error_placeholder_24dp)`

Comment: Saved my day. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions of Glide, the syntax for setting an error image is as follows:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
     .load(url)
     .error(Glide.with(imgView).load(R.drawable.ic_image_when_url_fails))
     .into(imgView);
```

Comment: What Version of Glide Library?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way which works perfectly in 2020 is

```
Glide.with(context)
      .load(image)
      .error(R.drawable.error_img) //in case of error this is displayed
      .into(imageView);
```